# Using Randbetween With Conditions In Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formatting, data-analysis

[image: My worksheet screenshot]

A round-robin schedule generated with even distribution of each of 21 teams playing approximately equal games in 14 given locations (no less than 1 game in each location, no more than 3 for each team).

The end product will be a table with Week, Home Team, Away Team, Location Home vs Away balance is not important, I have a template with everything populated except the location.

Any condition I could add?

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,14)
```

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: There are 21 teams and all matches are played in two weeks, so half the tournament is played after a week, now 14 locations to be randomized amongst all matches such that a team plays at least once in a location and not more than thrice.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the solver add-in, which is designed specially to solve logical models such as this.

https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/solver.html

Comment: If you could post the process for which is to be done would be appreciated.

Comment: That's not really how StackOverflow works, and that's a lot of work to ask of someone for free... Try walking through the provided training exercise, give it a try yourself, and post if you get stuck or have any questions so the community can help you troubleshoot.